# Linearization and Central Limit Theorems

Tags: probability-theory

This is an open-ended question about terminology and intuition. I'm a statistics graduate student. Someone once said to me "The key to proving Central Limit Theorems is linearization". I didn't know what this statement meant then, and don't now.

I'm currently reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01299.pdf). In Theorem 3.2, a random variable $R_{n}$ is defined and it is shown that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}nVar(R_{n})=0$. This is referred to as a linearization bound. Does anyone know why? Later in the paper a central limit theorem is proved and is basically concluded as a direct consequence of this bound.

I'm skipping a lot of details, but I'm hoping that this is some kind of routine technique that someone will recognize and be able to explain.

Thanks a lot!